Tailwind w-full fails with flexbox?
I'm debugging some style issues with my react website and simplified down my CSS code:
    <div style= {{display:'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <div>
            <div className="w-full h-full">
                <div className="flex flex-col border rounded bg-black relative">
                    asdofijdsdfij
                </div >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

I don't understand why the component is not expanding to full width. The third div specifies "w-full". If i remove one of the outer two divs, I can achieve the result that I want. It also works if I switch to basic css style like style={{width:"500px"}} instead of "w-full".
I need all the divs, this is just a simplified example. Can someone explain why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Since your outermost container is set to flex, if its child elements (the second layer container) do not specify a width, their width will shrink to the content width of their child elements.
Therefore, in this case, your second layer container does not have a specified width; its width is actually determined by its child elements, making w-full ineffective.
Additionally, since the width of the second layer container is determined by its child elements, when you set an explicit width for the child elements (e.g. w-[512px]), the container will adjust its width accordingly to fit the child elements.
If you want the child elements to fill the entire row by default as in normal layouts, you need to specify the width of the second layer container. In a flex environment, the preferred method is to use grow to fill the available horizontal space. However, in this case, you can also use basis-full or w-full to fill the entire row.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="grow">
    <div class="h-full">
      <div class="flex justify-center rounded bg-black text-white">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




If you cannot add a class to the second div, you can select it from its parent:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="flex flex-wrap [&>div]:grow">
  <div>
    <div class="h-full">
      <div class="flex justify-center rounded bg-black text-white">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



To prevent grow from being overridden by other styles, you can raise the selector specificity: [&>div]:!grow.

I actually can't modify that 2nd div. Is there a way to specify w-full with respect to a grandparent?

@JobHunter69 I think you mean that you can't directly add a class to the second div. You can select it from the parent element: [&>div]:grow.

I've updated the answer with this example. Please let me know if it still doesn't work.

Thanks It works. But one other thing, how exactly am I supposed to know that w-full does not force the parent to adjust a larger size? It's not a bug I'd be able to figure out on my own. Is this written in the docs anywhere?

@JobHunter69 In general, child elements can determine their own width based on the width of the parent element. However, in some cases, the parent element also determines its own width based on the child elements. For example, when the grandparent element has flex, or the parent element has w-fit and other similar classes, which can be contradictory. Therefore, one side will always not take effect. From the implementation, it seems that w-full doesn't take effect, while flex and w-fit continue to take effect.
